# How to open different R version from mac terminal?

Tags: r, macos, zsh

In the mac terminal, we can start an R session by simply typing `R`.

e.g.

```
s@MacBook-Pro Desktop % R

R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

This opens version 4.0.2 on my mac, but I have other versions installed (I can see them via [RSwitch](https://rud.is/rswitch/)).

How can I open a different version of R from the mac terminal? (and just to be clear, this isn't a question about [how to use a different R version in RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-RStudio-desktop))

#### Notes

```
sudo find /usr -path "*/bin/R" -print
/usr/local/bin/R
```

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/R*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  47 19 Jul 02:51 /usr/local/bin/R -> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R
lrwxr-xr-x  1 st    admin  37 15 Apr 22:41 /usr/local/bin/Redirect -> ../Cellar/xerces-c/3.2.3/bin/Redirect
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  53 19 Jul 02:51 /usr/local/bin/Rscript -> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript
```

```
find / -path "*/bin/R" -print 2> /dev/null | grep "R$"
/usr/local/bin/R
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/bin/R
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/bin/R
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/bin/R
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/bin/R
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/bin/R
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/bin/R
/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/bin/R
/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/bin/R
/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/bin/R
/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/bin/R
/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/bin/R
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/st/anaconda3/bin/R
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/st/anaconda3/pkgs/r-base-3.5.1-h539fb6c_1/bin/R
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/st/anaconda3/pkgs/r-base-3.5.1-h539fb6c_1/lib/R/bin/R
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/st/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/R
/Users/st/anaconda3/bin/R
/Users/st/anaconda3/pkgs/r-base-3.5.1-h539fb6c_1/bin/R
/Users/st/anaconda3/pkgs/r-base-3.5.1-h539fb6c_1/lib/R/bin/R
/Users/st/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/R
```

#### Update

Looks like after finding all R binaries with `find / -path "*/bin/R" -print 2> /dev/null | grep "R$"` we should be able to open any of them. But (example)

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/bin/R
```

opens 4.0.2. And

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/bin/R
```

also opens 4.0.2.

I cannot work out why?

Comment: I don't have a mac, but it should be sufficiently unix-like that this might work: `which R` will likely indicate a directory for R-4.0.2. Once you have that, see if the path has a version indicator in it. From there, look for similarly-named paths for the other versions of R.

Comment: does `which -a R` work on MacOS?

Comment: @BenBolker yep, `which -a R` and `which R` both return `/usr/local/bin/R`

Comment: then the other versions aren't in your path, which is a nuisance.

Comment: what does `find /usr -path "*/bin/R" -print` tell you?  Does RSwitch report anything about the paths of the versions it finds?

Comment: @BenBolker it returns `find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied /usr/local/bin/R`

Comment: Huh.  The "permission denied" stuff is ignorable.  Start your search at the system root directory instead, i.e. `find / -path "*/bin/R" -print` ? (It's possible that appending `2> /dev/null` to the end of the command will silence the "permission denied" errors)

Comment: @BenBolker What is the result of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/R*` ?

Comment: @BenBolker I tried with `sudo` - gives the same

Comment: @YuriGinsburg added to question for easier viewing

Comment: `find / -path "*/bin/R" -print 2> /dev/null | grep "R$"` ?

Comment: @BenBolker there was a lot of output - added to question

Comment: So you already found its locations. Now you can `ln -s /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/X.Y/Resources/bin/R /usr/local/bin/RX.Y` where X and Y are major and minor version numbers and invoke it as `RX.Y`

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I understand what you're suggesting but there's a problem before getting to that. When I run (example) `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/bin/R`, to my surprise, R version 4.0.2 starts (not 3.6 as we may expect). The same happens for each of the `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/X.Y/Resources/bin/R` paths. (this is before doing anything with symlinks). The anaconda paths above *do* load the expected R versions. But both `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/bin/R` and (continued)

Comment: `/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/bin/R` load R version 4.0.2 (not 3.4 as we may expect)

Comment: @BenBolker I added an update to the question (for ease of reading).